# Recommendation for syncing data on Windows Servers securely over the internet?

Tags: windows, ftp, files, file-transfer, synchronization

I have a Windows Server at a data center and an EC2 Windows Server running in the cloud.  In the *Nix world I know the answer to sync these would be rsync.  What are some good options for Windows?  Is FTP over SSL the only choice here?  What programs are good for syncing thousands of files over FTP?  Robocopy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [rsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650)?  I've used this particular Windows rsync distribution with great success.

There is a "friendly" rsync distribution for Windows, [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp), but I can't say much about it because I've never used it.

Obviously, you'll need to wrap the traffic in encryption, but either SSH or a VPN can take care of that for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on DeltaCopy (where I also discovered Syncrify).  The transport is a concern, as running SSH on windows is somewhat of a pain.  I've setup cygwin once before for this, but would rather just pay for a commercial product now.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution you can automate yourself or run on-demand, [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) can do mirroring similar to rsync (you'll need to have one of the directories available as a shared directory, first, though).

For a more automated solution, you might want to look into [DFS Replication](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserversystem/dfs/default.mspx).  Once setup, it's fairly automatic in syncing any changes.

Comment: You'd need to add a VPN to this solution to make it anywhere close to tenable.

Comment: I'd like to avoid the hassle of a VPN connection, though it certainly seems like a doable option with EC2 now.  I thought robocopy could work over FTP, but maybe not?

Comment: Unless I am missing it, no. Sorry... http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Comment: Yeah, a VPN (or otherwise secure connection) is absolutely needed.  Sorry, I'd meant to include that, but forgot.

Answer (score 0):

rsync or any of its front-end that suits your needs is good,
as for the encryption you can use putty to create an ssh tunnel between the two hosts

Comment: This is what @Evan suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

[FTP 7.5](http://www.iis.net/download/FTP) comes as a separate download. Install FTP 7.5 on your Windows Server 2008 instance. Use this [tutorial](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/304/using-ftp-over-ssl/) to setup your FTP over SSL